# Coffeemaker, expected value, variance

Tags: probability

I wanted to practice a bit, while I'm having a free time, and I spotted a problem, that I have some problems with:

> A coffeemaker, if it only works:
>
> - makes coffee, with the probability $0,9$
> - makes boiling water, with the probability $0,09$
> - breaks down, and does nothing anymore, with the probability $0,01$
>
> Let $X$ denotes the number of coffees, and $Y$ denotes the number of boiling water, that this coffemaker made before it broke down.
>
> a) find $\mathbb{E} X$
>
> b) find $Var X$
>
> c) find the smallest $a>0$ such that $P(X>n)=O(a^n)$
>
> d) are $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables?

Well, I think a) is easy. $X+Y$ is the number of operations this coffeemaker made before it broke down and $\mathbb{E}(X+Y)=\frac{1}{0,01}=100$ because of the geometric distribution. Moreover $\mathbb{E}X=n\cdot 0,9$ and $\mathbb{E}Y=n\cdot 0,09$ with a given $n$, because of the binomial distribution, so we have $\mathbb{E}Y=0,1\cdot \mathbb{E}X$ and $\mathbb{E}(X+Y) =\mathbb{E}X + \mathbb{E}Y$, so $\mathbb{E}X=90$. Is this reasoning correct?

b) I know $Var X = \mathbb{E}X^2 - (\mathbb{E}X)^2$, but I completely don't know how to find $\mathbb{E}X^2$ in this case.

c) I think, if I had $\mathbb{E}X$ and $Var X$ maybe Markov's or Chebyshev's inequality can help?

d) independence of random variables was always the hardest thing for me. No idea.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Some help:

Let call $Z=X+Y$. As you spotted, $Z$ is geometric with $p=1/100$, taking values in $0, 1 \cdots$ and $E[Z]=(1-p)/p = 99$.

Further, you've noticed that $X|Z$ is binomial $(Z,p)$, with $p=0.9/(0.9+0.09)=10/11$ hence $E[X|Z]=10/11 Z$
Now, $E[X] = E[E[X|Z]] = 10/11 \times 99 = 90$.

A similar reasoning can be used to compute $E[X^2]$

Comment: Now it's not obvious to me that $X|Z$ is binomial $(Z, 0.9)$. Why? It implies that $Y|Z$ is binomial $(Z, 0.1)$ and it's not true, because probability of making boiling water is $0.09$. I'm totally confused by this problem. I still don't see how to find $E(X^2)$.

Comment: @xan: Sorry, my mistake. Fixed. See if that's clear now.